# Why does the "feel" in this sentence stand in the past tense?

Tags: grammar

I saw the following sentence:

- *this was what love felt like?*

I can't understand why **felt** is in the past tense in this particular sentence. Is it because of Sequence of Tenses, or is it because of the meaning if the hero leads the story in the past tense?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Is this the same passage referred to in [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/279982/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-sentence-i-wondered-if-present-together-with-th)? If it's part of a story, these are usually told in the past tense.